# How to fix "name 'server' is not defined" error in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm setting up a python bot for my discord server. I'm trying to add a feature that when people join they type - and the bot will assign them to the role stated

I have tried to assign the role I want by using message.roles and server.roles but both still feed off the same error.

```
BOT_PREFIX = ('-')

...

#ComputerScience
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def Cs(member, *roles):
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="ComputerScience")
    await client.add_role(member, role)
```

When '-Cs' is typed in chat it shows give them the computer science role but instead I get:
"Ignoring exception in command Cs ...
NameError: name 'server' is not defined"

Comment: I never knew I had to define server I changed it to member.server.roles and tried member.roles and i got the error "AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'roles'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context), but not accepting it in the function signature of your command.  That context is where you can get the `server` from:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def Cs(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name="ComputerScience")
    await client.add_role(ctx.message.author, role)
```